# DNN (DotNetNuke) reading files locally

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is it possible for DNN to read files directly off a server? What I would like to do is be able to drag files into a created folder on my server and they will automatically be uploaded and show up on my DNN site. My main concern in this scenario is that I want to be able to go into the file on the server make changes and the changes will automatically be reflected on my DNN site without me having to reupload the file.

Comment: You could do this, but your application would need to have some kind of Timer setup that checked for changes and used ajax to update the page. Sounds like a unique situation, but IF possible, I'd rather upload the data in the file to a database and have dnn check that table.

Answer (score 1):

You can put things into the Portals/#/ folder, or a subfolder there, and have DNN AutoSynchronize the file-system (there's a scheduled task) so that the files show up in the File Manager in DNN.

I have a client who has a specific Uploads directory they FTP files into, and the synchronization process makes them available to their editors.